# how java backend get value in a dropdown from frontend

Tags: java

In java backend which method can be used to get value in the frontend dropdown?
eg: enter a country name in frontend dropdown, how can I pass this value to backend to search in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `back end` will expose a `rest api` that your `front end` will access via Rest Api call.
Your `dropdown list` will be filled by a list of country coming from your back end or a predefined list in your `front end`.

[image]

Google about [Rest Client](https://mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/), [Rest API](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) your will have a good understanding of the subject.